# Confusion in understanding a proof in Apostol's Calculus I

Tags: calculus

I'm using Apostol's Calculus I as my introductory book to the subject and I'm stuck trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1.13 (page 79) which, as I understand, provides a way to compute the value  of an integral. So I think it's important.

First of all, it follows from Theorem 1.12 (stating that every monotonic function on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$) that

$$\int_a^b t_n - \int_a^b s_n = \frac{(b-a)[f(b)- f(a)]}{n} = \frac{C}{n}\qquad \text{for every}\ n \geq 1\qquad (1)$$

**Theorem 1.13:**

Assume $f$ is increasing on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Let $x_k = a + k(b -  a)/n$, for $k=0,  1,. . . , n$. If $I$ is any number which satisfîes the inequalities

$$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k) \leq I \leq \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)\qquad (2) $$

for every  $n \geq 1$, then $I = \int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$.

**Proof:**

Let $s_n$ and $t_n$  be the special  approximating step functions  obtained  by subdivision  of the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal parts, as described in the proof of Theorem 1.12. Then the inequalities $(2)$ state that

$$\int_a^bs_n \leq I \leq \int_a^b t_n $$

for every $n \geq 1$. But the integral $\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$ satisfies the same inequalities  as $I$. Using equation $(1)$ we see that

$$0 \leq \left|I - \int_a^bf(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{C}{n}$$

for every $n \geq 1$. Therefore by Theorem 1.31, we have  $I = \int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$ as asserted.

---

Ending up with the last set of inequalities is what I haven't been able to understand. It's clear to me that the integral of $f(x)$ satisfies the same constraints of $I$, but I get confused in getting $I - \int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$ there.

The only explanation I gave myself is that if I subtract the leftmost expression in $(2)$ from the set of inequalities and apply the telescoping property to what I get in the rightmost I get

$$0 \leq I-\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k) \leq \frac{C}{n}$$

Then, if I assume $\frac{b-a}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k) = \int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$, i.e. the integral of $s_n$ equal to that of $f$, I get almost the same set of inequalities as in the last part of the proof. But as a proof, it does not seem to be a convincing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$I \leq \int_a^b t_n,$$

and

$$\int_a^bs_n \leq \int_a^bf(x)\,dx \implies -\int_a^bs_n \geq -\int_a^bf(x)\,dx $$
we have

$$I- \int_a^bf(x)\,dx \leq \int_a^b t_n-\int_a^b s_n.$$

Similarly, using the inequalities $\displaystyle \int_a^b s_n \leq I$ and $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx \leq \int_a^bt_n$ it follows that

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx - I\leq \int_a^b t_n-\int_a^b s_n \implies I-\int_a^bf(x)\,dx \geq -\left(\int_a^b t_n-\int_a^b s_n\right).$$

Then conclude

$$\left|I-\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right|\leq \int_a^b t_n-\int_a^b s_n= \frac{C}{n}.$$

Comment: That's a handy way of using the inequalities. Now, I think, I can keep going without remorse (:. Thank you.

Comment: @Jazz: You're welcome.